# WebSocket.async giving me error

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I am new to WebSocket. I am making a simple chat application. The code is giving me error.
Here is the code in which error occurs-

```
def chatSocket(nick:String)=WebSocket.async{ request=>
val roomActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[ChatRoom])
val channelsFuture=roomActor ? Join(nick)
channelsFuture.mapTo[(Iteratee[String,_],Enumerator[String])]
}
```

Error is- could not find implicit value for parameter FrameFormatter:play.api.mvc.WebSocket.FrameFormatter

Comment: I have solved my problem. I should have to use WebSocket.async[String] instead of WebSocket.async

Comment: please post your solution as an answer and accept it - that will mark the question as closed, and possibly help future visitors